# OOLUA compiler errors

Tags: c++, lua, compiler-errors, oolua

I'm trying to compile a simply program using OOLUA but I'm getting unexplainable errors.

The code:

```
#include <oolua.h>
#include <iostream>

class TestClass
{
public:
TestClass() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
~TestClass() { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};

OOLUA_CLASS_NO_BASES(TestClass)
OOLUA_NO_TYPEDEFS
OOLUA_CLASS_END

int main()
{
    OOLUA::Script vm;
    vm.register_class<TestClass>();

    OOLUA::run_chunk(vm, "obj = TestClass.new() ");
}
```

I am compiling with MinGW w64 4.9.2 i686. The errors it produces are:

```
7 error: 'OOLUA_NO_TYPEDEFS' does not name a type
16 expected '}' at end of input
251 error: expected unqualified-if at end of input
251 expected '}' at end of input
```

There are more macros which fail to compile when used, but currently it's failing to work with a simple program. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What version of oolua?

Comment: Assuming I'm reading things correctly `OOLUA_NO_TYPEDEFS` was removed in that version of oolua. You need to update to match.